# Can I compare Q-VALUE for the same action across different states?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

Dears,

I'm new with RL and try to apply to my project.
I've run RL with some example data and got the
My question is if I could compare the Q-values for the same current action across different prior actions?
for example,

- looking at the Q-values for "current action= CIO" with different prior actions.
- Q-value for CIO with prior action of ET3 is 135.99 and Q-value for CIO with prior action of CIO is 212.28.
  -Then, could I consider the CIO after CIO is better policy than the CIO after ET3 based on the Q-values 212.28 vs 135.99 ?

within the same prior actions, the higher Q-value , the better policy.
Then what about across prior actions? Can I still compare the Q-values numerically ?
If my question does not make sense, please advise me.
Thanks for your kind help in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my view, you can, but interpretation might not be straightforward. Q-values are estimation of action-state value function. It means that Q-values can be interpreted as expected reward after taking a particular action in a particular state. If you compared action **a<sub>1</sub>** in a state **s<sub>2</sub>** to an action **a<sub>1</sub>** in a state **s<sub>1</sub>**, you could see that comparison as a comparison of an expected reward for action **a<sub>1</sub>** between states. So, you could say that committing an **a<sub>1</sub>** is better in some states than in others.

For instance, if your action is buying a dog (**a<sub>1</sub>**) and your state is being homeless (**s<sub>1</sub>**) or having a house with a garden (**s<sub>2</sub>**), we can assume that your expected reward for an action-state with a house is higher (let's assume your dog will be healthier and happier). If you were in (**s<sub>1</sub>**), you could think "If I had a house, buying a dog would be better for me than it is now". Is such an interpretation helpful for you? I don't know, but I hope you can come up with some hands-on ideas now :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. If I gave another example about that, let's say that there are patients with different previous treatments (different prior actions as presented in the table of my original question). the current treatment is same but the prior treatment was different. In this case, based on the numeric Q-value , could we interpret the current treatment(C) with an  A prior treatment  shows better than the current treatment(C) with a B prior treatment ?  :-) Thanks for your time in advance again.

Comment: @tree I would be cautious with that interpretation. If state a) is healthy and state b) is dying regardless of any cure, Q-value of taking treatment for b) will be far lower despite the fact that the cure effect might be stronger than for a healthy person (eventually the patient will die).

Comment: Many Thanks for your kind reply again. Just to make you understand better my question, the patients' basic status are pretty similar and only previous treatments could be different but the current  action for treatment is the same. In that case, the higher Q-value, the better option for the current treatment after different prior therapies ? :-)

Comment: @tree let's say that the higher Q-value, the higher the expectation of positive results after the treatment.